# How to use numpy.where with logical operators

Tags: python, numpy, where-clause, logical-operators

I'm trying to find the indices of all elements in an array that are greater than a but less than b. It's probably just a problem with my syntax but this doesn't work:

```
numpy.where((my_array > a) and (my_array < b))
```

How should I fix this? Or is there a better way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried logical operators like & instead of and?

Comment: Just substituting and with & doesn't work, but I just found that this works: numpy.where((my_array > a) & (my_array < b) == True)

Comment: @user1803782: Can you explain it what sense replacing `and` with `&` doesn't work?  It's the standard way to solve this problem.

Comment: I'm actually not sure why it gave an error the first time. Now it does work. My bad. But thanks.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Here are two ways:

```
In [1]: my_array = arange(10)

In [2]: where((my_array > 3) & (my_array < 7))
Out[2]: (array([4, 5, 6]),)

In [3]: where(logical_and(my_array > 3, my_array < 7))
Out[3]: (array([4, 5, 6]),)
```

For the first (replacing `and` with `&`), be careful to add parentheses appropriately:  `&` has higher precedence than the comparison operators.  You can also use `*`, but I wouldn't recommend it:  it's hacky and doesn't make for readable code.

```
In [4]: where((my_array > 3) * (my_array < 7))
Out[4]: (array([4, 5, 6]),)
```

Comment: what do you mean with "hacky" ? and why does it always return "(array([4,5,6]),)" instead of just returning "array([4,5,6])" ? What is the idea behind the "tuple without a second thing in it"-syntax of the returned thing?

Comment: @usethedeathstar: (1) the hacky bit is subjective.  I guess my issue with it is that (for me, at least) the surface reading of the code doesn't clearly match the intent.  (2) For `where`, it returns a tuple because in the general case `where` operates on two `n`-dimensional arrays and returns an `n`-tuple of results; here you're seeing the special case where `n=1`.  The tuple container is a bit ugly, but being inconsistent with the higher-dimensional cases would probably be uglier.  (Yay!  More subjectivity!)

Comment: so since in this case, we get a 1D array, the tuple is 1 item long, and in the 2D case, you just get an "x-index" array and a "y-index" array in your tuple, showing the x,y coordinates of the points in your 2D array that are good according to the logic-composition you made?

Comment: @usethedeathstar: Yes, exactly.

Comment: Bah: "operates on two n-dimensional arrays" should be "operates on an n-dimensional array" above.